# Android v23 PDFreader keep crashing

Tags: android, pdf-rendering

I am new here however wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. This is part of my app in which I want to read PDF file from assets and display in the fragment. Android version used 23.4.0

```
public class PDFFragment extends Fragment {

private ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor;
private PdfRenderer pdfRenderer;
private PdfRenderer.Page currentPage;
private ImageView image;
private Button buttonPrevious;
private Button buttonNext;

public PDFFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_research_paper, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // Retain view references.
    image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    buttonPrevious = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_previous_research);
    buttonNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_next_research);

    //set buttons event
    buttonPrevious.setOnClickListener(onActionListener(-1)); //previous button clicked
    buttonNext.setOnClickListener(onActionListener(1)); //next button clicked

    int index = 0;
    // If there is a savedInstanceState (screen orientations, etc.), we restore the page index.
    if (null != savedInstanceState) {
        index = savedInstanceState.getInt("current_page", 0);
    }
    showPage(index);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        openRenderer(activity);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("Fragment", "Error occurred!");
        Log.e("Fragment", e.getMessage());
        activity.finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try {
        closeRenderer();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (null != currentPage) {
        outState.putInt("current_page", currentPage.getIndex());
    }
}

 //Create a PDF renderer
private void openRenderer(Activity activity) throws IOException {
    // Reading a PDF file from the assets directory.
    fileDescriptor = activity.getAssets().openFd("research_paper.pdf").getParcelFileDescriptor();

    // This is the PdfRenderer we use to render the PDF.
    pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor);
}

 //Closes PdfRenderer and related resources.
private void closeRenderer() throws IOException {
    if (null != currentPage) {
        currentPage.close();
    }
    pdfRenderer.close();
    fileDescriptor.close();
}

 //Shows the specified page of PDF file to screen
private void showPage(int index) {
    if (pdfRenderer.getPageCount() <= index) {
        return;
    }
    // Make sure to close the current page before opening another one.
    if (null != currentPage) {
        currentPage.close();
    }
    //open a specific page in PDF file
    currentPage = pdfRenderer.openPage(index);
    // Important: the destination bitmap must be ARGB (not RGB).
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(currentPage.getWidth(), currentPage.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    // Here, we render the page onto the Bitmap.
    currentPage.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
    // showing bitmap to an imageview
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    updateUIData();
}

 //Updates the state of 2 control buttons in response to the current page index.
private void updateUIData() {
    int index = currentPage.getIndex();
    int pageCount = pdfRenderer.getPageCount();
    buttonPrevious.setEnabled(0 != index);
    buttonNext.setEnabled(index + 1 < pageCount);
    getActivity().setTitle(getString(index + 1, pageCount));
}

private View.OnClickListener onActionListener(final int i) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (i < 0) {//go to previous page
                showPage(currentPage.getIndex() - 1);
            } else {
                showPage(currentPage.getIndex() + 1);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

}

Logcat error message

```
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.getPageCount()' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.PDFFragment.showPage(PDFFragment.java:115)
                  at com.example.PDFFragment.onViewCreated(PDFFragment.java:61)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: getPageCount()' on a null object reference --> pdfRenderer is null , initialize it

Comment: did you try with buildToolsVersion "25.0.1" ??

Answer (score 1):

There looks to be at least 2 different issues right now affecting `PdfRenderer` behaviour.

First one is related to bug in v2.2 of gradle plugin (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=224273) that affects treatment of following gradle config that's required to ensure pdf is not compressed (as mentioned in https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic).  This is required as `PdfRenderer` needs a `ParcelFileDescriptor` that is seekable (so file cannot be compressed). You can reproduce this issue with google's `PdfRendererBasic` sample by using 2.2 version of gradle plugin.  A fix for this is to revert to v2.1.2 of plugin.

```
android {
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "pdf"
    }
}
```

The other issue doesn't seem to be occurring in `PdfRendererBasic` sample but is in other apps (including mine!) and seems to be related to packaging of apk ([Android Studio - PDFRendererBasic - Unable to replace sample.pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345596/android-studio-pdfrendererbasic-unable-to-replace-sample-pdf) contains detailed discussion on issue).

One suggestion in last linked SO article was to read from `raw` folder instead....however this didn't work for me for some reason.  What I had to do in the end was ready pdf from SD card using something like following

```
    String pdfPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sample.pdf";
    mFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(new File(pdfPath), ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);

    // This is the PdfRenderer we use to render the PDF.
    mPdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(mFileDescriptor);
```